# Identify Highest Level of Products Customers Purchased

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to identify the highest level of products customer purchased but have no idea how to make it happen. The sample shown below. Each customer may buy different products at different stores for different level of each product at different date.

```
-- Create a sample data table
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Day Date,
    Customer VARCHAR(50),
    Gender  VARCHAR(50),
    Store#1 VARCHAR(50),
    Store#2 VARCHAR(50),
    Store#3 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Sales VALUES 
('2/1/2021',    'Tom',  'M',    'C1','','S3'),
('4/2/2021',    'Jerry','M',    'M2','C1','S3'),
('4/12/2021',   'Tom',  'M',    'S1','M2','C2'),
('6/21/2021',   'Ben',  'M',    'C1','M2','S3'),
('7/21/2021',   'Ben',  'M',    'C2','M1',''),  
('7/21/2021',   'Jerry','M',    'S2','C3','M1'),
('8/1/2021',    'Alisa','F',    'C3','M2','S2'),
('9/30/2021',   'Ben',  'M',    'M2','',''),    
('10/11/2021',  'Jerry','M', '' ,'M3','S1'),
('12/12/2021',  'Alisa','F','M2','C1','S2'),
('2/12/2022',   'Rachel','F','M1','C1','S1');
```

My goal is to identify the highest level of each type of product each customer purchased and summarize the results as table below.  Mark "Yes" at the highest level of each type of product the customer purchased.

Here is the level of each product:

[image]

Here is the expected outcome:

```
CREATE TABLE expected_outcomes (
    Customer VARCHAR(50),
    M VARCHAR(50),
    F VARCHAR(50),
    C1 VARCHAR(50),
  C2 VARCHAR(50),
  C3 VARCHAR(50),
  M1 VARCHAR(50),
  M2 VARCHAR(50),
  M3 VARCHAR(50),
  S1 VARCHAR(50),
  S2 VARCHAR(50),
  S3 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO expected_outcomes VALUES 
('Tom', 'Yes','','','Yes','','','Yes','','','','Yes'),
('Jerry','Yes','','','','Yes','','','Yes','','','Yes'),
('Ben', 'Yes','','','Yes','','','Yes','','','','Yes'),
('Alisa','','Yes','','','Yes','','Yes','','','Yes',''), 
('Rachel','','Yes','Yes','','','Yes','','','Yes','','');
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the expected outcome in plain text just like sample data. Images are not available.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur updated. Sorry for that.

Comment: you forgot to add the products to your sample data?

Comment: @siggemannen the items/values listed under store# are products/level.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Day Date,
    Customer VARCHAR(50),
    Gender  VARCHAR(50),
    Store#1 VARCHAR(50),
    Store#2 VARCHAR(50),
    Store#3 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Sales VALUES 
('2/1/2021',    'Tom',  'M',    'C1','','S3'),
('4/2/2021',    'Jerry','M',    'M2','C1','S3'),
('4/12/2021',   'Tom',  'M',    'S1','M2','C2'),
('6/21/2021',   'Ben',  'M',    'C1','M2','S3'),
('7/21/2021',   'Ben',  'M',    'C2','M1',''),  
('7/21/2021',   'Jerry','M',    'S2','C3','M1'),
('8/1/2021',    'Alisa','F',    'C3','M2','S2'),
('9/30/2021',   'Ben',  'M',    'M2','',''),    
('10/11/2021',  'Jerry','M', '' ,'M3','S1'),
('12/12/2021',  'Alisa','F','M2','C1','S2'),
('2/12/2022',   'Rachel','F','M1','C1','S1');

  

WITH unpivoted AS (
    SELECT
        Customer,
        Gender,
        Product,
        CASE
            WHEN Product LIKE 'C%' THEN 'C'
            WHEN Product LIKE 'M%' THEN 'M'
            WHEN Product LIKE 'S%' THEN 'S'
        END AS Category
    FROM
        (SELECT Customer, Gender, Store#1 AS Product FROM Sales
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Customer, Gender, Store#2 AS Product FROM Sales
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Customer, Gender, Store#3 AS Product FROM Sales) AS subquery
    WHERE Product <> ''
),
max_product AS (
    SELECT
        Customer,
        Gender,
        Category,
        MAX(Product) AS MaxProduct
    FROM unpivoted
    GROUP BY Customer, Gender, Category
)
SELECT
    Customer,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS M,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS F,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'C1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS C1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'C2' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS C2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'C3' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS C3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'M1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS M1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'M2' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS M2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'M3' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS M3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'S1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS S1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'S2' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS S2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MaxProduct = 'S3' THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END) AS S3
FROM max_product
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY Customer;

**Result**
```

| Customer | M | F | C1 | C2 | C3 | M1 | M2 | M3 | S1 | S2 | S3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alisa |  | Yes |  |  | Yes |  | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |
| Ben | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |  |  | Yes |
| Jerry | Yes |  |  |  | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |  | Yes |
| Rachel |  | Yes | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |  |
| Tom | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |  | Yes |  |  |  | Yes |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GGq9Lx1K)

Comment: Thanks Horaciux a lot! I will test it on the real data.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: a simple pivot like this should be done with the appropriate functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16